# Can you tell me how to declare this array arr[n[j]]={0}; with all zeroes

Tags: c, arrays, loops, for-loop

I stuck with a big  assignment problem which has this snippet of code

```
int t;
scanf("%d",&t);
int n[t],p[t];
for(int i=0;i<t;i++)
{
    scanf("%d %d",&n[i],&p[i]);
}
 for( int j=0;j<t;j++)
{

    int k=0;
    int arr[n[j]];
    arr[n[j]]={0};

    for(int i=k;i<n[j];i++)
    {

        arr[i]=arr[i]+1;
        k++;

    }

}
```

but  in the line arr[n[j]]={0}; has an error("expected expression before '{' token") can you tell me how to declare all zeroes in this array

Comment: What's it supposed to do? `arr` is a local array and it doesn't seem to be used in any meaningful way and it'll disappear after the loop. May be, you can describe the problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: `memset(arr, 0, n[j] * sizeof arr[0])`

Comment: Hmm... the proposed duplicate do have the solution but it's not the same problem. This is not initialization - this is an assignment. Not sure it's a good duplicate but again - the solution is in the dup.

Comment: @4386427 Yeah, an out of bounds assignment. This question would benefit from a clear exposition of what the code is supposed to do.

Comment: @Bob__ I didn't look at the rest of the code - I only looked at the part OP asked about. Well - true - the code seems a bit strange ... `k++;` is useless as `k` is never used. And given that `arr` is starting out as all-zero, the loop will just set all elements to 1. So the body of the loop could be `arr[i]=1` and then there is no need to set the element to zero in the start. Stramge.